# Magento2 - Remove/edit classes from navigation

Tags: magento2, jquery, navigation

I have set up a new magento2 store and I added some **jqery-ui items ( accordion and tabs)** and for them to work, I was included the **jquery.css** in my **_extend.less** inside my custom theme.

Unfortunately now it added to the standard magento2 navigation multiple animations and icons that i don't want, because the navigation has jquery classes by default.

My question now: How do i remove those classes from the menu, so i can use the jquery.css? Or how can i solve this, without styling all the jquery by hand?

Thank you.

[image: navigation classes]

Answer (score 0):

Just open file topmenu.phtml and change:

From:

```
<ol class="nav-primary" data-mage-init='{"menu":{"responsive":true, "expanded":true, "position":{"my":"left top","at":"left bottom"}}}'>
     <?= /* @noEscape */ $_menuHtml?>
     <?= $block->getChildHtml() ?>
</ol>
```

To:

```
<ol class="nav-primary">
      <?= /* @noEscape */ $_menuHtml?>
      <?= $block->getChildHtml() ?>
</ol>
```